# Working via proxy with netty 3.4.2.Final

Tags: java, netty, socks

Is there any possiblity to use Netty as it is described here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Maybe there are some options like:

```
System.getProperties().put("socksProxySet","true");
System.getProperties().put("socksProxyHost","127.0.0.1");
System.getProperties().put("socksProxyPort","1080");
```

I tried it but netty does not take properties and do not proxies request via socks proxy.

```
ChannelFuture future =
                    bootstrap.connect(
                            new InetSocketAddress(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort()));
```

My netty client connects to netty server via websockets.

Java NIO does not support proxy. Netty is based on Java NIO. I just hoped that such possibility exists/can_be_added to netty.

Thank you!

Comment: SOCKS proxy server is configured already? Or you would like to use netty-server as SOCKS server?

Comment: No, socks server is already running - it is not netty at all. I don't want to use netty sever as socks server. I want to work with my netty server via soks proxy. I found that java.nio does not support proxy mode at all - and netty is based on java.nio. But maybe something is changed...

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple. You have to create your listener with own handler. Example can be found here :
https://github.com/shenfeng/async-http-client

classes:

me.shenfeng.http.ConnectionListener 
me.shenfeng.http.SocksHandler

Netty from 3.6.2.final contains package *.socks:
http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/socks/package-summary.html. 
So this object model can be used to encode/decode socks message to/from socks server.

Comment: Does this work only for HTTP or could it work with any TCP connection?

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using WebSockets connection from client to server, and web-sockets protocol is based on HTTP, then such structure should work (it slightly differs from what you wrote):

```
//System.setProperty("socksProxySet","true"); //it's commented, because it seems to be not necessary
System.setProperty("socksProxyHost","127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("socksProxyPort","1080");
```

But as you are saying that it is not working for you, then I would recommend to check official netty's proxy [example](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3.2/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/proxy).

Comment: Thanks, but the link the you posted redirects on server implementation. It works in next way: all requests that comes on 'localaddres:localport' are redirected to 'remoteaddress:remoteport'

But I don't need it. Situaton is next:
1) I have a netty server.
2) I have a netty client.
3) I have socks proxy between them.
I neet to connect to the netty server with netty client via this socks proxy.

Comment: Ok, got it, I must have misunderstood the requirements.

Comment: Btw, have you tried to pass SOCKS parameters as JVM parameters? And you are passing params onyl for client, right?

Comment: Sure I tried as it is described in initial post. It does not work.

Comment: NIO doesn't support this properties: http://blog.tsunanet.net/2010/08/java-nio-and-overengineering.html. Your link with example describes usual socket proxy, but Alexey Usatov asked about socks proxy